# How to generate the key to unlock bootloader to unlock OEM

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, bootloader-lock, nokia

I want to install [Lineageos](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/DRG/) on my [Nokia 6.1 Plus](https://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_6_1_plus_(nokia_x6)-9178.php).

### Info

- But I understood Nokia is not supporting officially
- I cant see `OEM unlocking: Allow the bootloader to be unlocked` is DISABLED in developer's options

### Already Tried

So far I have ran below commands on my Ubuntu connected to Nokia 6.1 PLus(enabled USB debugging too) but no luck

```
$ adb devices
List of devices attached
DRGID190811065XX    device

$ adb reboot bootloader

$ sudo fastboot devices
DRGID190811065XX    fastboot

$ sudo fastboot oem unlock
...
FAILED (remote: Flashing Unlock is not allowed
)
finished. total time: 0.000s
```

I have already checked below links

- https://www.techmesto.com/guide-unlock-bootloader-nokia-android-phones/ But the tool they provide is blocked by my anti-virus. I don't want to use it without knowing it
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081263/adb-android-device-unauthorized
- https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bootloader-unlock-generating-fastboot-unlock-key.4076421/

### Questions

- How to unlock bootloader for Nokia 6.1 Plus?(Which requires unlock key)
- What is procedure to generate the key to unlock bootloader in general for any android phone

Comment: Anti virus warning may be because of unsigned drivers (it costs $$$ to sign drivers accepted by Microsoft) // You can see on the website of the developer how to [remove the driver verification](https://hikaricalyx.com/how-to-use-uu4/) // Of course, if you don't trust this developer, then you shouldn't try this method on windows or alternatively try his Linux/Mac version

Comment: Linux link (after seeing your profile) https://twitter.com/Hikari_Calyx/status/1545819694808018944?t=VrI5Cn7XCRIhEI5zu1Xkjw&s=19 //locking of bootloader is done by OEM, if they don't want users to unlock. It's proprietary and there is no universal method (your second question)

Comment: Unless there is some exploit in the system, you can't generate the key.